# DDOS perl script

Tags: perl

Im trying to write a script that uses `tcpdump` under `openbsd` than monitor firewall logs.
My goal is to genereate an alert if a source ip address is equal to evry line [ line duplicate  ]  from the tcpdump output, example :

```
rule 30/0(match): block in on pppoe0: SRCIP:(88.198.46.51) -> DESTIP:(109.226.27.19): ICMP echo request, id 1070, seq 1, length 64
rule 30/0(match): block in on pppoe0: SRCIP:(88.198.46.51) -> DESTIP:(109.226.27.19): ICMP echo request, id 1070, seq 2, length 64
rule 30/0(match): block in on pppoe0: SRCIP:(88.198.46.51) -> DESTIP:(109.226.27.19): ICMP echo request, id 1070, seq 3, length 64
rule 30/0(match): block in on pppoe0: SRCIP:(88.198.46.51) -> DESTIP:(109.226.27.19): ICMP echo request, id 1070, seq 4, length 64
rule 30/0(match): block in on pppoe0: SRCIP:(88.198.46.51) -> DESTIP:(109.226.27.19): ICMP echo request, id 1070, seq 5, length 64
rule 30/0(match): block in on pppoe0: SRCIP:(88.198.46.51) -> DESTIP:(109.226.27.19): ICMP echo request, id 1070, seq 6, length 64
rule 30/0(match): block in on pppoe0: SRCIP:(88.198.46.51) -> DESTIP:(109.226.27.19): ICMP echo request, id 1070, seq 7, length 64
rule 30/0(match): block in on pppoe0: SRCIP:(88.198.46.51) -> DESTIP:(109.226.27.19): ICMP echo request, id 1070, seq 8, length 64
```

ip 88.198.46.51 is attempted dos attack.
my code so far:

```
open(SNIFF, "/usr/sbin/tcpdump -s 1024 -enlti pflog0 |");
 while(<SNIFF>){
       $|++;
       $_ =~ /(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)(.)(\d{2,5}) (>) (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(.)(\d{2,5})/;
       my ($sip, $port) = ($1, $7);
       my $bad_ip = $sip;
        if($bad_ip eq $p_ip){
            $count++;
            if($count >= 8 && $print){
              print "Attack Detected: $sip\n";
                          system("echo $sip");
                          #system("/sbin/pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf");
                          $print = 0;
            }
```

Comment: my code is not working!. Can you give me direction. thanks!

Comment: where are you setting $p_ip ?

Comment: `system("echo $sip")` — ***really?***

Comment: @tchrist That's funny. I didn't see that one. =)

Comment: I learned a new way to print things from this. (-;

Comment: @Qtax, oooh, how about `system("echo $_") for split //, $sip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample input, I don't see a single line that matches the first part of your regex:

```
/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(\.)(\d{2,5})/
```

(Note, that I anticipated that if you're looking for a dotted decimal, that you really want `\d+\.` not just `\d+.`.)

You can match `(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)` with your input, but the rest is not going to match. That's your issue.